# SQL Server Execution Plan puzzle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Under SQL Server 2008 R2, working with a database about 1.5 Terabytes in size:

We're testing partitioning the tables in the database. Database A is non-partitioned, B is partitioned.

Query is run via execute SQL, the one where the query is passed in as a string.

Query in A runs in a few seconds.
Query in B runs in over a minute.

Add the RECOMPILE option to the query, query runs in B same time as in A.
Remove the RECOMPILE. Time reverts back to slow time.

Bounce B's instance.
Query without RECOMPILE is slow.
Query with RECOMPILE fast.
Remove RECOMPILE. Query slow again.

We've tried all the usual methods of clearing the execution plan caches that you see online.

It would appear that two separate execution plans are generated. One for the one with recompile, one for the one without. Both seem to persist.

Anyone seen this behavior?

We're trying to get rid of the slow execution plan so that the query will always adopt the fast plan since the SQL is always the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rebuild your indexes. and rebuild statistics on each table on both servers.

Comment: An additional note: The query takes a single parameter. The above description applies with the query parameterized. If the value for the parameter is placed directly into the SQL, it's always fast.

Comment: You're running SQL with local variables? The optimizer doesn't know the value of the parameter, so it will optimize it for an unknown value. With recompile changes that. Are you always using the same value for the parameter or could this just be parameter sniffing problem?

Comment: Using `optimize for` might help in the problem, with it you don't end up recompiling the plan every time, and might get good enough plans every time.

Comment: @collumww  Yes. that yet another reason against dynamic SQL. The server can't optimize it. I would advice against EXEC() any day. Use a stored procedure, or a view, or... anything else ;) Now, if you must, then use sp_executesql instead. BTW, I want to stress the importance of  rebuilding of the statistics.

Comment: Are the partitions "serving" the query ?

Comment: If you look at the two query plans, are you getting partition elimination in one and not the other?

Comment: I'll need to look into things a bit more Monday to check some of the things you folks are asking about. Some I can answer now: Stats and indexes well cared for no problem there. Can't help the dynamic SQL. My group is on the back end of things as the DBAs and much of the SQL possibly cannot be changed. Yes, this is being run via sp_executesql. The partitions are serving the query fine as indicated by the fast execution with the recompile. The puzzle is why the slow plan cannot be cleared off the server using all the usual methods.